# How to pass a function to another react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have this Icon component, which upon clicking opens a dialog box

```
export default class Icon extends Component {


    look (imgdes, i) {
        const openDialog=()=> {
                    document.getElementById(i).style.display = "block";
      }

        const  closeDialog=()=> {
                document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
      }
        return (
                <div key={i} onClick={openDialog}>
                    <Dialog closed={closeDialog}/>
                </div>
            );
        }


    render () {
        return (
                <div className="pro" >
                    {this.state.img.map(this.look)}
                </div>
        );
    }
};
```

this is dialog box component, which upon clicking the X made by span tag should close it

```
    export default class Dialogbox extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Dialog">
         <span className="close" onClick={this.props.closed}>&times;</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the problem lies in the fact that opendialog is working,but closeDialog doesn't work.I was trying to pass closeDialog as props but it didn't work. Is there any other way to do it or can someone suggest an improvement in this code?

Comment: thats is why we use a state management library, flux or redux.

Comment: Actually I am still learning how to use redux. If there is an easier way to do it via redux then I will implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try a different approach

**Dialog component file**

since you need multiple dialogs. we need identifiers to uniquely identify the dialogs, thats why i will use data attributes.

```
 export default class Dialogbox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div data-id={this.props.id} className="Dialog">
         <span data-id={this.props.id} className="close" onClick={this.props.closed}>&times;</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Icon Component file**

you are using document.getElementById . so it must have a unique identifier id. otherwise it will not work. thats why we will pass
props id to uniquesly identify each dialog.

```
export default class Icon extends Component {
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.look=this.look.bind(this);
       this.show=this.show.bind(this);
       this.close=this.close.bind(this);
       this.state = {open: false};
    }
    show(ev){
     const id=ev.target.dataset.id;
     document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
     this.setState({open: true});
    }
    close(ev){
     const id=ev.target.dataset.id;
     document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
     this.setState({open: false});
    }
    look (imgdes, i) {
        return (
                <div key={i} data-id={i} onClick={this.show}>
                    <Dialog closed={this.close} id={i}/>
                </div>
            );
        }

    render () {
        return (
                <div className="pro" >
                    {this.state.img.map(this.look)}
                </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: This method is not working, says "Cannot read property 'style' of null".

Comment: @SanketSingh i have updated the answer. please check.

Comment: still doesn't works, on outputting const id using console.log, gives undefined, :(

Comment: then try ```e.currentTarget.dataset```

Comment: This method is working and dialog box is showing up, but it doesn't close when X is clicked. But discovered an interesting thing. When X is hit, just after close() is executed, show() also executes itself-
0 show
0 close
0 show
0 close
0 show

Comment: interesting. this should not happen. are you sure you have not called it again

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is not called from within the function

Comment: @SanketSingh what was the issue ? why wasnt it working

Comment: I don't know, but using a variable to store whether it is opened or not made it work

Comment: @SanketSingh setting state caused re-render that updated UI. since we are using imperative approach to hide the modal. its better to use declerative way of react to handle views.